# I've tried using {multline} but it keeps giving me error msg

Tags: latex

I added amsmath to package
I have a very long equation I wanna break into two.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{multline}
c^E_t(i) + w^P_t l^P_t(i) + w^I_t l^I_t(i) + \frac {1+r^{bE}_{t-1}}{\pi_t} b^E_{t-1}(i) + q^k_tk^E_t(i) + {\psi}(u_t(i))k^E_{t-1}(i) \\
+ \frac{y^E_t(i)}{x_t} + b^E_t(i) + q^k_t(1-{\delta})k^E_{t-1}(i)
\end{multline}
\end{equation}
```

I get the following message... help!

> See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H   for immediate help.
> ...
>
> l.113 \begin{multline}

?

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Yes, your header is also needed to understand what doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `multline` enviroment you could use a `split` enviroment. This enables you to split the equation where need.

```latex
\begin{split}
c^E_t(i) + w^P_t l^P_t(i) + w^I_t l^I_t(i) + \frac {1+r^{bE}_{t-1}}{\pi_t} b^E_{t-1}(i) + q^k_tk^E_t(i) + {\psi}(u_t(i))k^E_{t-1}(i) \\
+ \frac{y^E_t(i)}{x_t} + b^E_t(i) + q^k_t(1-{\delta})k^E_{t-1}(i)
\end{split}
```

If you want to align the two lines at a specific character type a `&`.

For further information see [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/split).

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that this is due to the fact that the environment `multline` **must not** be nested within an `equation` environment. (`split`, from the same package [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), instead does). [One reference.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253965/49683)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%\begin{equation}
\begin{multline}
c^E_t(i) + w^P_t l^P_t(i) + w^I_t l^I_t(i) + \frac {1+r^{bE}_{t-1}}{\pi_t}
b^E_{t-1}(i) + q^k_tk^E_t(i) + {\psi}(u_t(i))k^E_{t-1}(i) \\
+ \frac{y^E_t(i)}{x_t} + b^E_t(i) + q^k_t(1-{\delta})k^E_{t-1}(i)
\end{multline}
%\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you uncomment lines 4 and 10 here, you get exactly the same error message.